# Restructure Win Forms application to MVVP pattern – possible future WPF version

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mvvm

I’ve recently started working on a Win Forms application which needs some improving and restructuring. There are chances that a WPF version of the application is done in the future and I’m considering restructuring the Win Forms app to the MVVM pattern.  The purpose is that when the time comes to develop the WPF I would only have to focus on creating WPF views and reuse the code from the previous version.
I’ve looked at a few posts on developing a Win forms application using the MVVP pattern and it does seem possible to develop Win Forms application using the pattern.
I’d like to know if the approach is advisable and if restructuring an existing Win Forms application to a MVVM pattern would ease the work load when developing a WPF version.

Comment: I can hardly imagine developing winform application without using code behind.

Comment: You could also consider to do a WPF version of your restructuring and embed that in your Windows Forms application. 
I had a smiliar approach in an existing application: everything that had to be restructured or rewritten was done in WPF and bound via MVVM and with usage of ElementHost embedded in the WinForms Framework.
Only drawback is the mixed visual appearance.

Comment: You might be interested in the sample application of the WAF WinForms Adapter (http://waf.codeplex.com/releases/view/52583). It uses the MVVM pattern and provides a WinForms and a WPF Presentation layer which can be exchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good idea in my mind. Because a really big part why MVVM is so good in WPF, is the WPF bindings infrastucture. 
WinForms doesn't have such abilities, binding support is way lower. That is why WinForms use MVP pattern, where Presenter is responsible for providing data to the view.
You can try writing purely MVVM models, but then you'll have to write quite a lot of ugly code inside your views in order to bind to the models and update them.
I would suggest stick to MVP, as this is quite a good aproach for WinForms, it creates well structured components, and then it is easy to recreate the same functionality in WPF and MVVM.

Answer (score 3):

As per other respondents the problem here is the presentation layer, which WinForms doesn't handle as easily as WPF.

That said, based on my experience, many legacy WinForm applications have a lot of business and data layer logic in the forms code.

I see no reason why you shouldn't ensure that the code is separated out into distinct data layer, business logic and GUI in preparation to a possible move to WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Some months ago I wrote a small winforms app with something like MVVM, just for fun. I used my own binding...
Binding code was placed in codebehind, and was looked like:

```
 this.Bind(src: x => x.ViewModel.SearchCriteria, dst: x => x.txtSearchCriteria.Text, mode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

btw, I haven't finished this app, but it was interesting to try:)

To summarise:
1) is it possible? - Yes, I've tried to do that, and it worked.
2) is it hard to implement? - No, not very hard.
3) do I suggest to try this in real project? - No, it is indeed better to use MVP instead.

Answer (score 2):

As Vladimir said, you probably *can* redesign your Winforms project to use MVVM pattern. But the question is: is it worth it?
You have to literally reinvent the wheel and wrap you Winform controls in classes that support  WPF-like binding.
Imagine you develop a WPF application and put all the business in code-behind. It's doable but it's not right IMO and it surely is ugly.

I'd separate my data access layer to be able to use it in possible future WPF projects. But I would try to document the business in the application instead of migrating to MVVM, to make it easier to build a WPF application from scratch.